# global variable is not set in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, variables, definition, mapael

```
$(function(){
    var bwr_w = null; //global variable

//below function gets the dynamic data 
    function myfunc() { 
        var val = '2011'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "allmaps.php",
            data: "year="+val ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){                  
                bwr_w= result.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //want to set the data again

            }
        });
    }

    myfunc(); //my dynamic function gets called

    $(".container_map").mapael({                                    
        map : {
            name : "usa_states"
        },
        plots: {
                bwr_w //this should work as per myfunc()
        }
    });

});
```

**I am always getting bwr_w value as null even if I get a some value in ajax return**
I want my bwr_w to be set as global variable so that when I get some result from ajax it should change my map pins.

Comment: bwr_w is not really "global", `window.bwr_w` would be. you need to wait the return callback

Comment: I tried window.bwr_w = null; but I am still getting value as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. This means that your `myfunc` is exited *before* the data is returned from the AJAX call. To fix this issue, put all code dependent on the returned data within the callback:

```
$(function () {
    var bwr_w = null; //global variable

    //below function gets the dynamic data 
    function myfunc() {
        var val = '2011'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "allmaps.php",
            data: "year=" + val,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                bwr_w = result.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //want to set the data again
                $(".container_map").mapael({
                    map: { name: "usa_states" },
                    plots: { bwr }
                });               
            }
        });
    }

    myfunc();
});
```

If you want different logic executed on each call to `myfunc` pass it in as a callback function:

```
$(function () {
    //below function gets the dynamic data 
    function myfunc(callback) {
        var val = '2011'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "allmaps.php",
            data: "year=" + val,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                var bwr_w = result.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //want to set the data again
                callback(bwr_w);
            }
        });
    }

    myfunc(function (bwr) {
        $(".container_map").mapael({
            map: { name: "usa_states" },
            plots: { bwr }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me what exactly should I do in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting what I want now. Thanks a lot for your great help.BTW I have used the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

See here

```
$(function(){
    var bwr_w = null; //global variable

    //below function gets the dynamic data 
    function myfunc(then) { 
        var val = '2011'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "allmaps.php",
            data: "year="+val ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){                  
                then && then(result);                   
            }
        });
    }

    myfunc(function() {

      bwr_w= result.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //want to set the data again

    $(".container_map").mapael({                                    
        map : {
            name : "usa_states"
        },
        plots: {
                bwr_w //this should work as per myfunc()
        }
      });
    }); 
});
```